# ActivityManager does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS warning

Tags: android, android-activity, android-logcat

I'm getting a warning message on my android phone (Nexus 5) from the `ActivityManager`. It doesn't seem to be from any particular application. And it keeps displaying about ever 2 seconds. Anyone know why this is happening? Or what I should look into to find out more about it?

[image]

Comment: Figure out who 10078 is. I'm not sure if that is an app's process ID or an app's user ID, though I suspect that it is the latter.

Comment: I was unable to find any process with the PID of 10078 (found all processes by using "adb shell ps"). How would I find an app's user ID?

Comment: Well, the brute-force way would be to write a utility that iterated over the apps installed, via `PackageManager`, as you can get their UID that way. I assume that there's a simpler solution, but I don't know what it is off the top of my head. And if the value is consistently 10078 (per your comment on the one answer), that's really unlikely to be a PID, if it is from an ordinary Dalvik app, as our processes just don't stick around forever.

Comment: have you gotten any solution to your problem? i am getting the same in my logs...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an app is using permission for GET_TASKS which was deprecated in Lollipop: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_TASKS

The error is specifying that REAL_GET_TASKS be used instead and there's a bug report about this issue (though I'm not spending the time to see if its the exact same issue): https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2347

Sorry (I looked it up now), 10078 is the UID according to the code:

```
private boolean isGetTasksAllowed(String caller, int callingPid, int callingUid) {
...
if (!allowed) {
    Slog.w(TAG, caller + ": caller " + callingUid
    + " does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output");
}
```

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java

The caller is a method of ActivityManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29

I have no idea what 10078 uid actually is on your device. You can try 'adb shell' then 'id' and hopefully it shows up.

Comment: Plugged my phone in again today. The warning is still going with the caller still being 10078. Ran "adb shell ps" in commandprompt and did not see any process with that PID. http://i.imgur.com/3qiWQRu.png

Comment: Updated my answer as its actually a UID.

Comment: Plugged in phone again, still getting the 10078 number. I don't see anything on the adb shell with that id:
http://i.imgur.com/urk45G8.png

Comment: Ah ha! It's the Avast! mobile security app that's doing it. I ran the following command in adb [dumpsys package | grep -A1 "userId=10078"] and it showed the following:
http://i.imgur.com/ZI3SHoI.png

So that solves what app is doing it. Not sure what to do about it. The message will stop if I force stop the app, but I'd rather have it running than not.

Comment: You can ask the developer if they know about it. It looks like it should be a quick fix but then all quick fixes look that way.